# Redefine \footnote to change color of index in Latex

Tags: latex, xelatex

For my work I shall make it possible to change the color of the footnote index optionally.

I found a way to change the color, but it is not flexible.

```
\RequirePackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{red}{RGB}{165,30,55}
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\textcolor{red}{\arabic{footnote}}}

\begin{document}
a footnote\footnote{lalala}
\end{document}
```

this works. But this does not:

```
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}[1]{\textcolor{#1}{\arabic{footnote}}}
\begin{document}
a footnote\footnote[red]{lalala}
\end{document}
```

I think it is because `\footnote` already has one optional parameter for the index number.
Is there a way to change it?

Comment: which documentclass do you use? Do you need the preserve option to specify a number? Would it be ok to use a different name, say `\cfootnote`?

Comment: actually I am working on a new documentclass a designer made for my boss. I guess it wouldd be better to preserve it, but anyway if you have an idea to solve my problem with some new command like '\cfootnote' it would be great

Comment: Is the documentclass based on some standard documentclass? Without knowing the code it will be really hard to find a general solution.

Comment: Yes it is based on scrartcl `\LoadClass{scrartcl}` and uses scrletter `\usepackage{scrletter}`

Comment: Dear reviewers, this is a pure tex problem and unrelated to programming. I think it would be best if it would be migrated to tex.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a new command, one could do something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\RequirePackage{xcolor}

\newcommand{\cfootnote}[2][black]{%
    {\color{#1}\footnote{#2}}%
}

\begin{document}
a footnote\cfootnote{lalala}


a footnote\cfootnote[red]{lalala}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Another approach with redefining the footnote:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{scrletter}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\let\oldfootnote\footnote
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\RenewDocumentCommand{\footnote}{ O{} m O{black}}{%
    \deffootnotemark{\color{#3}\textsuperscript{\thefootnotemark}}%
    \ifstrempty{#1}{%
        \oldfootnote{#2}%
    }{%
        \oldfootnote[#1]{#2}%
    }
}

\begin{document}

test\footnote{text}[red]

test\footnote{text}

test\footnote[42]{text}

test\footnote[42]{text}[blue]

\end{document}
```

[image]